# Eliminating repetition with C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, dry

```
#include "ArrayList.h"

template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(): innerArray(new T[0]), len(0) {
    // constructor stuff
}
template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>::~ArrayList() {
    // destructor stuff
}
... on and on and on ...
```

In this code, I have to write `template <typename T>` and `ArrayList<T>::` before **every** member function in the entire class.

Is there any way to eliminate this repetition ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), so I can do something like

```
#include "ArrayList.h"
// do some magic

ArrayList(): innerArray(new T[0]), len(0) {
    // constructor stuff
}
~ArrayList() {
    // destructor stuff
}
```

Comment: You know you need to keep the implementation in the header anyway, right? So why not define them inside the class?

Comment: I don't think that's considered repeating yourself...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Wait, doesn't the implementation go in the `.cpp` and the definition in the header?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'd say an identical line before every single method in my class would be repeating myself...

Comment: For templates, the implementation has to be visible to TU's that use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Also, `innerArray(new T[0])` is not right. Do `innerArray(nullptr)` instead.

Comment: @Doorknob In the case of non-template classes, sure; you can separate the implementation from the interface. Not so with templates. You MUST have the implementation available when the template is instantiated by the compiler. So you should just define them inline since they need to be in the header anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can use a macro:

```
#define DEFINE_ARRAYLIST_TEMPLATE(F, ...) template <typename T> \
                                          A<T>::F(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Use it to do this:

```
DEFINE_ARRAYLIST_TEMPLATE(ArrayList) : innerArray(nullptr), len(0)
//                                                ^^^^^^^ < my earlier suggestion
{}

DEFINE_ARRAYLIST_TEMPLATE(ArrayList, int n) : innerArray(new T[n]), len(n)
{}

DEFINE_ARRAYLIST_TEMPLATE(~ARRAYLIST)
{}
```

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain your downvote and I will be happy to improve this answer.